# Unable to Mount my Android 4.4 in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: android, mtp

I bought the phone which has android 4.4 version and i am using ubuntu 12.04 and i am unable to connect this to my PC.

Comment: Install mtp-tools package first `sudo apt-get install mtp-tools` and then try to connect your phone to Ubuntu pc via USB cable.

Comment: Well, can you specify what your phone is?
Or you can follow an official guide from [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html).

Answer (score 1):

Please post details about the issue.

Android devices use MTP (Media Transfer Protocol) file transfer system. So, in order to mount your device on Ubuntu, you need MTP file system package installed. Using MTP is kind of tricky. And it's unstable for newer android versions. So using Go-mtpfs seems better in order to mount Android 4.0+ devices.

[I found a working solution here.](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/12/how-to-mount-android-40-ubuntu-go-mtpfs.html)

I was facing the same problem with my android device. But Go-mtpfs has solved the issue for me.

I hope it works for you as well.

Comment: This is a more up to date solution that automatically mounts android 4 devices: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/01/upgrade-to-gvfs-with-mtp-support-in.html